# CNN de rgb a escala de grises

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy trabajando con esta CNN y tiene un problema, cuando lo trabajo de 2 a 5 clases funciona bien pero cuando trabajo de 6 clases en adelante el accuracy se estanca en numeros bajos de 10 a 20% durante todo el entrenamiento por más que lo deje toda la noche.

Estoy tratando de arreglar eso y **quiero cambiar RGB a escala de grises pero no se como hacerlo**. Se que el 3 en esta linea significa RGB pero si coloco un número que no sea 3, o si no coloco nada da error y no corre, entonces **¿cómo hago para ponerlo a trabajar en escala de grises? **o al menos como hago para que el accuracy avance de 10-20% cuando uso las clases que necesito (11) ?

```
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ='same', input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import image
from mlxtend.evaluate import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


K.clear_session()
data_entrenamiento = 'C:\\Users\\min2\\Desktop\\cnn\\train'
data_validacion = 'C:\\Users\\min2\\Desktop\\cnn\\test'

epocas=20
longitud, altura = 200, 200
batch_size = 32
filtrosConv1 = 32
filtrosConv2 = 64
tamano_filtro1 = (3, 3)
tamano_filtro2 = (2, 2)
tamano_pool = (2, 2)
clases = 11
lr = 0.0005

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.3,
    zoom_range=0.3,
    horizontal_flip=True)

validacion_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

imagen_entrenamiento = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_entrenamiento, 
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

imagen_validacion = validacion_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_validacion, 
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

print(imagen_entrenamiento.class_indices)

pasos_entrenamiento = imagen_entrenamiento.n//imagen_entrenamiento.batch_size
pasos_validacion = imagen_validacion.n//imagen_validacion.batch_size

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ='same', input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro1, padding ='same'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Flatten())

cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))

cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

H = cnn.fit_generator(
    imagen_entrenamiento,
    steps_per_epoch=pasos_entrenamiento,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=imagen_validacion,
    validation_steps=pasos_validacion)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a ir por partes.

### Número de clases

A mayor número de clases una misma red neuronal, va a empeorar su accuracy, el por qué es claro. **Es mucho más fácil acertar dos clases que acertar seis**. Te lo demuestro con un ejercicio.

Tenemos 2 clases, por ejemplo indentificar perros y gatos, y creamos una red neuronal que acierta el 50% de las veces. Por otro lado en otra tenemos otra red neuronal pero hay diez clases (caballo, rana, etc) y acierta un 30% de las veces. ¿Qué red neuronal es mejor?

La respuesta claramente es la segunda, ya que en la primera has hecho una red neuronal que no sirve para nada, ya que si clasificas de forma aleatoria tirando una moneda al aire, el accuracy te va a dar un 50%. Sin embargo la segunda tienes 10 clases y aciertas un 30%, eso es tres veces más que si lo hicieses de forma aleatoria, por lo tanto la red neuronal te está ayudando (aunque no sea muy buena)

### Cambiar a escala de grises

`Tensorflow` tiene una función para convertir los tensores de imágenes a escala de grises `tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale()`

Usando tu código la función `ImageDataGenerator()` tiene un parámetro que es `preprocessing_function` en el cual tu puedes agregar una función de procesamiento para que se utilice durante la carga y procesado de imágenes. Esta parte de tu código quedaría así:

```
import tensorflow as tf


entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.3,
    zoom_range=0.3,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    #Añadimos la función de preprocesaod a blanco y negro
    preprocessing_function= tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale)

validacion_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                       #Hacemos lo mismo en el conjunto de validación
                                       preprocessing_function= tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale)
```

Si quieres saber más sobre la función `tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale()` puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial de Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale)

Para saber más sobre generadores de imágenes y sus parámetros puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial de Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

### ¿Cómo hago para mejorar el accuracy?

Esto ya es una pregunta más amplia que no tiene una respuesta concisa. Por lo que mi respuesta va a ser general.

Si una red neuronal no obtiene buenos resultados es porque **es demasiado sencilla para un problema complejo**, por lo que tienes que hacer una red neuronal más compleja para que sea capaz de extraer correctamente las características de tus datos. Esto se hace con prueba y error y leyendo artículos, ejemplos, documentación, etc, sobre este tema. Es decir con **experiencia y aprendizaje.**

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que cambiar el 3 por 1 en input_shape. Te quedaría así:

```
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ='same', input_shape=(longitud, altura, 1), activation='relu'))
```

Luego agrega color_mode='grayscale' en:

```
imagen_entrenamiento = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
data_entrenamiento, 
target_size=(altura, longitud),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical',
color_mode='grayscale')

imagen_validacion = validacion_datagen.flow_from_directory(
data_validacion, 
target_size=(altura, longitud),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical',
color_mode='grayscale')
```